# Why is wall time(elapsed time ) less than cpu time for parallel programs?

Tags: linux-kernel

Can anyone tell me why is wall time(elapsed time ) less than cpu time for parallel programs?

Comment: show me how you find out that it is less?

Comment: Core t (s)   Wall t (s)        (%)
       Time:    70252.704     9466.785      742.1
                         2h37:46
                 (ns/day)    (hour/ns)
Performance:        9.127        2.630

Comment: This is the output of the log file when i ran an insruction of GROMACS which is related to life sciences

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
wall time:  <-------------->   16
    CPU 1:  ## #############
    CPU 2:      ##########
 CPU time:                     25
```